# How to SELECT multiple rows with condition that applies to multiple columns in those rows?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, rows

I got a table like:

```
  Users:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    User_id: User_name: User_email: User_has_neck: User_has_eyes: User_has_head: User_has_hair
    1      | John     | jon@jk.com| yes          | yes          |  sometimes   |  sometimes
    2      | Kate     | kte@jk.com| yes          | yes          |  sometimes   |  some
    3      | Mark     | mrk@jk.com| yes          | sometimes    |  sometimes   |  sometimes
    4      | Kora     | sometimes | yes          | yes          |  yes         |  some
    5      | Acts     | act@jk.com| sometimes    | sometimes    |  sometimes   |  some
    6      | Jerw     | sometimes | yes          | yes          |  yes         |  too_much
    7      | Dude     | sometimes | sometimes    | sometimes    |  yes         |  too_much
    8      | Ninja    | nja@kl.com| yes          | yes          |  yes         |  too_much
```

Now, I need to Query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE <NO_COLUMN_IS_EQUAL_TO_sometimes>;
```

A column might have data like; `'yes'`,`'some'` but `NOT` `'sometimes';`

How can this be done?... any suggestion is highly appreciated.

I tried,

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE *#@!$%^()**#$ NO IDEA.....` ***'--------->stackOverflow'***

Comment: Do you know for sure how many columns will be there in the table? Or is that unknown?

Comment: I don't mind the DONW VOTE.... But please let me KNOW why I am getting the PUNISHMENT...(just leave a comment before DOWN VOTING please, I beg. Thank You MASTERS!!!)

Comment: @shree.pat18 sure, the issue is that the rows might have over 54COLUMNS... That's why am looking for a way to having this done without enlisting Columns... thx

Answer (score 2):

Just do this with explicit comparisons in the `where` clause.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE 'sometimes' not in (User_has_neck, User_has_eyes, User_has_head, User_has_hair);
```

EDIT:

In your example, you could generate the list with a query such as:

```
select group_concat(column_name separator ', ')
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'users' and table_schema = ???;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, though, the rows might have over 54 COLUMNS... That's why am looking for a way to having this done without enlisting Columns.. thx again

Comment: @UniversalGrasp so you've got to do a bit of typing. You could write code that generates this list by the information schema.